# Compare Two List and return Data from first list based on Ids in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var solutionItems = solutionInfoResponse
  .Items
  .Where(x => solutionInfoResponse
     .ProductGroup
     .FirstOrDefault(p => productGroupIds.Contains(p.GroupId))
     .Items
     .Any(it => it.Id == x.ItemId))
  .ToList();
```

Here I am getting `List` of `FirstProduct` group only with exist in `ProductGroupsIds`, so I want all product group with existing same
condition. Please Help me.

Here

```
 public class ProductGroup
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public List<ProductGroupItem> Items { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
  public class ProductGroupItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
       
    }
```

and

```
public class SolutionItem
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

}
```

Finally

```
   public class SolutionInfoResponse
    {
        public List<SolutionItem> Items { get; set; }
        public SolutionInfo SolutionInfo { get; set; }
        public List<ProductGroup> ProductGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Note, that `FirstOrDefault` can return `null`, that's why `?.Items?.Any(it => it.Id == x.ItemId) ?? false` to be a safier approach

Comment: Could you, please, provide `FirstGroup` class definition?

Comment: @KuttyRajeshValangai I'm not sure to fully understand what you are asking, but isn't your problem the `FirstOrDefault` ? You want to get all ProductGroup where the condition `productGroupIds.Contains(p.GroupId)` is `true`, is that it? If that is the case, try remplacing the `FirstOrDefault` by `Where` and `.Items` with `.SelectMany(p => p.Items)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible that the same item can be in *several* groups we should not use `FirstOrDefault` but `Where`.
We obtain all such groups and then check if there's any `groupItem` with required `Id`:

```
var solutionItems = solutionInfoResponse
  .Items
  .Where(item => solutionInfoResponse
     .Groups
     .Where(group => productGroupIds.Contains(group.GroupId))
     .SelectMany(group => group.Items)
     .Any(groupItem => groupItem.Id == item.Id))
  .ToList();
```